# Error: Unable to resolve module ./vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

getting error after adding expo-modules-core in react native app with expo.

> error: Error: Unable to resolve module
> ./vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf
> from
> /home/alavi/IdeaProjects/3d-viewer/shopconnect-mobile/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/MaterialCommunityIcons.js:

```
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-asset-utils": "^3.0.0",
    "expo-gl": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.1.1",
    "expo-three": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-three-orbit-controls": "^2.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "mediasoup-client": "^3.6.29",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "three": "^0.133.1",
```

Comment: did you install react-native-vector-icons?

Comment: yes,  i have install react-native-vector-icons.